# Enabling APNs in iOS app after it was created

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an iOS app which uses Push Notifications. I recently uploaded the first version to the App Store and I have turned on the Push Notifications in the Application Services in the app's App ID in Apple Developer Console. It says "Configurable" now. After that I got an email from Apple with a warning:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app includes an API for
>   Apple's Push Notification service, but the aps-environment entitlement
>   is missing from the app's signature. (...)

Then I found out that in XCode, on the Capabilities tab I need to enable Push Notifications. I did it, then created a new version and uploaded it, then I didn't get such a warning. Looks promising so far.
My problem is that I don't quite know where are the certificates for the APNs. I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging which requires to upload a development and a production certificate.
The internet is full of ways to create these certificates manually. Although Apple says always that XCode can do it automagically, which I'd prefer too. I just don't know where those are and whether created or not yet.

In Apple Developer console, I have two certificates created when I uploaded the first version of the app: a development and a distribution certificate. If I click on the APNs Auth Key, there's nothing displayed (not sure if it's a problem)

What do I need to do to automatically generate (or just find if done already) the certificates by XCode?
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Push Service you have to create certificates manually and upload them to Firebase Console.

Comment: Why is Apple telling me this then: `Request Certificates with Xcode
Xcode is the easiest way to request certificates. Connect your device to your Mac and click Use for Development in Xcode's Organizer window. Sign in with the Apple ID associated with your iOS Developer Program membership and Xcode will automatically generate your certificates.`

Comment: I don't know apple only create provisional Certificates Automatically because push certificates need .CSR file

Comment: because this file is create in Keychain which need permissions

Comment: OK, so it seems that you really can't create these automagically. Thanks for the quick answer!